# Try to use an evaluator JaninoEventEvaluator in logback. But does not work to filter out depending on condition

Tags: logback

Try to use an evaluator JaninoEventEvaluator in logback. But does not work to filter out depending on condition.

My configuration of logback.xml is given below.

```
<appender name="durgaDlyFileSQL" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
  <File>${durga.log.file.name.SQL}</File>
  <encoder>
    <pattern>${ScreenConversionPattern}</pattern>      
  </encoder>
  <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
    <evaluator name="loggingTaskEval" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator">
    <expression>
System.out.println("MDC: " + mdc + " " + mdc.get("screenName")); 
String screen = (String) mdc.get("screenName");

    if ((screen == null) ||
    screen.equals("Server Type Entry/Amend/Cancel")) {
      return false;
    }

    </expression>
  </evaluator>
  <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
  <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
</filter>
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">  
  <fileNamePattern>${durga.log.file.name.SQL}.%d{${finch.log.file.DefaultRolloverFrequency}}</fileNamePattern>
</rollingPolicy>
```

and the output of the log:

```
[17 Mar 2016 13:42:18.437][Server Type Entry/Amend/Cancel][durga_admin]  TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder 83 binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - durga_admin 
[17 Mar 2016 13:42:18.438][Server Type Entry/Amend/Cancel][durga_admin]  TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder 83 binding parameter [4] as [TIMESTAMP] - 2016-03-17 08:16:23.0 
[17 Mar 2016 13:42:18.439][Server Type Entry/Amend/Cancel][durga_admin]  TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder 83 binding parameter [5] as [TIMESTAMP] - 2016-03-17 08:16:23.0 
[17 Mar 2016 13:42:18.440][Server Type Entry/Amend/Cancel][durga_admin]  TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder 83 binding parameter [6] as [VARCHAR] - durga_admin 
[17 Mar 2016 13:42:18.441][Server Type Entry/Amend/Cancel][durga_admin]  TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder 83 binding parameter [7] as [INTEGER] - 0
```

I do not want log when screenName = "Server Type Entry/Amend/Cancel"

I'm using janino 2.5.10 and logback 1.1.7 and all the stuff is running on a tomcat 7.0.47

Answer (score 1):

JaninoEventEvaluator needs an expression that returns value from all conditional branch. Otherwise it will complain saying:`org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: Method must return a value`

You can change your expression to return true at the end if your condition does not match.

Check the example here: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#JaninoEventEvaluator